# Array wraparound with modulo of unsigned

Tags: c++, c, arrays, random, circular-buffer

I'm trying to implement a [lagged Fibonacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagged_Fibonacci_generator) pseudo-random number generator for integers up to some maximum. It maintains an array of values

```
int values[SIZE] = { /* 55 seed values */ };
```

and uses the following function to return the next value

```
unsigned lagfib()
{
    static unsigned idx = 0;
    int r = values[idx];

    /* The following does not work: */
    values[idx] = (values[(idx-24) % SIZE] + values[(idx-55) % SIZE])
                 % MAX_VALUE;
    idx = (idx+1) % SIZE;
    return r;
}
```

In effect, `values` should be a simple ring buffer that is always full. The subtraction and modulo should wrap the index around to the end of the array. `SIZE` should always be at least 55, but I want to round up to 64 to speed up the modulo.

But apparently, I've got the modulo calculations wrong and I don't know how to fix them. Changing the index type to `int` doesn't improve things.

(PS.: Yes, `static` data is bad style, but I want this to be readable for both C and C++ programmers, since it pertains to both languages.)

Comment: Why is `static` data bad style (in C, or did you mean C++ only)?

Comment: In C it's also bad style, since it leads to non-reentrant code.

Comment: @endolith: because it makes code non-threadsafe.

Comment: @larsmans: Why is that bad?  Or rather, when is it bad?  The language construct wouldn't exist if it were always bad, would it?

Comment: @endolith: I tend to write my code in a thread-safe way, unless I'm doing experimentation as in this case. So yes, `static` has a use and this was it, but only this was a one-off program.

Comment: @larmans: You can always get around your `static` data problem (*and* the reentrancy problem) by passing in the state (in this case `idx`) as a pointer, and working with that: `unsigned lagfib(unsigned* idx)`. User then just initializes it manually to 0 (or uses `lagfib_init(&state)`) before the first call. If you're unsure whether `idx` is always going to be an `unsigned`, you can hide its type behind a typedef, or hide *it* inside of a (non-opaque for implementation reasons, opaque API-wise) `struct lagfib_stat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If e.g. `idx` is less than 24, you'll get wraparound to the other end of the number range of `unsigned int`.  55 is not a divisor of e.g. 2^32, so this will not give you correct results.

I can see two options:

- Maintain three separate `idx` variables, offset by 24 and 55 respectively.
- Do e.g. `(idx - 24 + SIZE) % SIZE`.

Actually, I would choose the first option, and avoid the modulo entirely by rewriting the increment as:

```
idx = ((SIZE-1) == idx) ? 0 : (idx+1);
```

which will probably be way faster than calculating modulo.

Comment: +1 and accepted, but I'm assuming modulo 64 is compiled to a bitmask op. I really should refresh my modular arithmetic.

Comment: @larsmans: Oh, so you do actually have `SIZE == 64` in your code?

Comment: @larsmans: Incidentally, have you taken into account that your seed values will need to be in "reverse" order?

Comment: Back to `SIZE=55`, and noticed that `idx + 55 - SIZE` is now `idx` so I only need two indexes. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Lets take `idx = 0` and `SIZE = 64`.

`(idx-24) % SIZE`  will be a very large value (`4294967272` for a 32-bit int )as `idx` is unsigned, making it an invalid index.

To get the circular effect you should add `SIZE` ***before*** taking modulus:

`(idx-24+SIZE) % SIZE`  will be `(0-24+64)%64` which evaluates to `40`.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing values with a negative index. For example:

```
-24 % 55 == -24
```

So you'll need some logic to wrap around to the end of the array. C/C++ doesn't do this for you.